# freeing an double pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

```
int size_of_daten = 5;
char *data[size_of_daten];
char *normal_Pointer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
int i;

for(i=0; i<size_of_daten; i++) {
    data[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
}

data[0] = "0";
data[1] = "1";
data[2] = "2";
data[3] = "3";
data[4] = "4";

printf("data[2] %s\n",data[2]);

strcpy(normal_Pointer,data[2]);

for(i=0; i<size_of_daten; i++) {
   free(data[i]);
}

free(data);
```

I just tried this... even I freed the array as I malloced it... also I copied the value of `data[2]` and didn't point at it... so that shouldn't be the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to copy the strings `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. into your `data` array: you can't just use `=` to copy strings, you'll need to use a string library method like [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Once you assign to your array elements those literal strings, e.g.: `data[0]= "0";`
, the array elements no longer point to the memory that you've allocated, they point to memory that doesn't belong to you, and you can't use `free`. You've lost the references to your memory blocks from `malloc`, causing a memory leak.

Furthermore, you can't do `free(data);` because it wasn't allocated using `malloc`: it's an array allocated on the stack.

Comment: is there any way to free for example data[0] = "0";... or just point it to NULL ... guess not as in c there is no garbage collector

Comment: the memory for literal strings is managed for you: typically it's part of the _data_ portion of your executable, hence in read-only memory. So they'll exist for the lifetime of your program. Only manage memory that you've allocated yourself using `malloc`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you copy data into an array of `char`s you've previously allocated:

```
data[0]= "0";
data[1]= "1";
data[2]= "2";
data[3]= "3";
data[4]= "4";
```

You're *overwriting* the pointers with the address of 5 new pointers. At this point you've lost the address of the memory you had allocated, and when you call `free` you're calling it on the statically allocated string `"0"`.

You need to use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to copy bytes from one character array into another:

```
strcpy(dest[0], "0");
strcpy(dest[1], "1");
/* etc */
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data[0]= "0"` you are overwriting whatever malloced address returned by `malloc`.
What you should be doing instead is

```
strcpy(data[0], "0");
strcpy(data[1], "1");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, assignment to the elements of data after allocating leaks the previously allocated memory.  When you assign a char *, you assign only the char *: it doesn't copy the string, it overwrites the pointer.

Second, you're freeing data declared on the stack.  You define data with:

```
char *data[size_of_daten];
```

This describes an on-stack array of character pointers.  It will go out of scope when your function returns, and freeing it manually will blow up.